# VLANs / Isolation on Home Network

Tags: networking, router, switch, vlan

I own a duplex and live in one part and rent out the other.  My goal is to share the internet but have 2 isolated networks: Mine and the Tenant's.  Both networks should have ethernet and Wi-Fi.

Currently, I have a Motorola Surfboard SB6190 cable modem.  It has only 1 RJ-45 which feeds to the WAN port of a TP-Link AC1900 router.  This router has a few of my devices hanging directly off of it and it also feeds an unmanaged 8 port switch (in order to expand the number of ports) which feeds my half of the house.  The TP-Link router also feeds to the WAN port of a D-Link DIR-860L router.  The D-Link router then feeds to another unmanaged 8 port switch (again in order to expand the number of ports) which feeds the Tenant's half of the house.

> TL;DR - What are the recommendations in terms of hardware to manage 2 VLANs each with Wi-Fi on 1 trunk with basically complete separation and optionally allow monitoring & throttling?

The routers are configured to be on different subnets: `192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0` and `192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0`.  This works and I assume it gives me the network isolation I want.  The 2 routers provide independent Wi-Fi and the Tenant network should stop at their router and should not be able to escalate out (I hope).

However, now that everything has an ethernet port, I am again out of ports.  I could buy another 8/16/24 port unmanaged switch and patch it in, but I wanted to simplify things.

So, I bought a TP-Link TP-SG1024DE 24 port managed switch figuring I would try my hand at VLANs and such.

My initial thought was that I could do router on a stick and separate the switch ports into 2 VLANs (Mine and Tenants).  However, the router on a stick approach is designed to facilitate communication across VLANs which is not something I really want.  My conclusion is that if all devices get their IPs from the same router, then they will end up in the same subnet.  Even though the switch will isolate the packets, the packets will just go up to the router and back down to the other VLAN which is not my goal.  Most guides mention virtual sub-interfaces on the gateway which I guess allows intelligent IP assignment, but I doubt my consumer grade router is intelligent.  Please correct my understanding if I am wrong.

My next thought was to reserve a port (port 1) which would connect to the modem.  The remaining ports would be divided into 2 VLANs with each VLAN having a unique VPID and 1 router.  A 3rd VLAN would tie all ports together so they can talk with the modem such that untagged traffic on the reserved port will go to a 3rd VPID.  This is what is documented in a lot of places, but I cannot resolve 2 things in my head:

1. I am unclear on the level of isolation given that the 3rd VLAN bridges all ports.  Seems like the traffic between the modem and each router would be visible to each other.  I guess this is allayed by the fact that the Tenant does not have admin access to the router.
2. How will the routers get their external IP address?  Seems like both router's WAN ports would need to also share a VLAN with the modem's port and then use another port to talk with their respective VLAN.  Further, my ISP is comcast and they (or the modem) is finicky about who it talks to.  E.g., when I replaced a router, I had to clone a MAC address just to get the modem to assign the router an IP address.  I guess somewhere during Comcast registeration, they choose to talk only to a specific MAC and nothing else.  And lastly, I assume Comcast will only give me 1 IP address without $.

So, most recent thought is to go back to Modem `->` My Router WAN `->` Tenant Router WAN.  Then My Router would connect to switch port 1 and Tenant Router to switch port 24.  Ports 1-12 would be VLAN-10 and ports 13-24 would be VLAN-20.  However, this means the switch I bought is (for my purposes) only a couple steps better than 2 unmanaged switches taped together.  I am fine with that because it was the same cost as two 16 port switches, but it is not as elegant a solution as I thought it would be.

The stuff I am finding online is either Cisco enterprise level stuff or simple home personal networking.  Topology-wise, this is much closer to simple home personal networking, but I do not think any of the consumer grade hardware really supports it.

So, what are the recommendations in terms of hardware to manage 2 VLANs each with Wi-Fi on 1 trunk with basically complete separation and optionally allow monitoring & throttling?  I have a few things about using Linux as a software router.  I have always wanted to dabble in raspberry pi but never had a compelling reason to do so.  Can someone elaborate on what that topology would look like (assuming it is possible)?

My background: I am a software engineer, so I (think I) have a strong technical background, but I lack the practical experience when it comes to network administration.  Huge fan of stackoverflow, but first time posting in serverfault.

Note, I noticed these types of questions tend to get flagged as 'off-topic'.  I know it is a bit of a long winded question and have asked for clarification at many points, but I clearly defined my goal and am asking 'what hardware topology can achieve my goals?'.  If someone decides to close it, at least have courtesy to point me to a more appropriate forum.

Comment: The tenant being behind a second NAT he sees all your devices, but you don't see his. I have voted to move this question to Super User, as we only deal with business networks here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend the following; using a firewall as they are intended for applications like these.

Connect a firewall behind your modem, and use that as your primary router. On this firewall, configure 3 zones, **Internet**, **Home** and **Tenant**. Then you can easily configure the firewall to allow traffic to and from the **Internet** to both zones, but not between the **Tenant** and **Home** zones. You can then assign a subnet to both these two zones, as well as a VLAN, which can then be trunked through your network to where they need to go.

VLANs are should really be called "virtual switches", as that's the way to view them, aka. you create multiple VLANs instead of having to buy and install multiple switches and pull more cable.

Comment: Thank you for the tip about VLAN.  Having now tinkered with them a bit, I think that is a much more accurate description.  Because without a 3rd parent router/NAT, I was struggling with how to separate them into different subnets (which still may not be the right way to view it).  Regarding firewalls, I had been looking into pfSense but I was hoping for a more zero configuration setup.  Will test it out.

Comment: pfSense is a good solid firewall if you want to go the DIY route, otherwise there are plenty cheap firewalls available like Ubiquity and others!